# Download data from webmap made with leaflet

Tags: qgis, leaflet

Can I download the data from a webmap made available from leaflet? I am referring to these dataset (https://www.vectorbase.org/popbio/map/), for which I wish to download the data for Europe? Is there a way to import these data into QGIS providing the link of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would complete (although it can still be known how data come from the server) Spacedman's answer by saying that reverse-engineering the [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call to retrieve data with the finest granularity (at the level of each point) would give nothing but an important coding/development stage to accomplish first. Indeed, data aggregation (averaging and so on) is  server-sidely performed. Furthermore, no [geoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) format specification adopted here. An example of call being :

```
https://www.vectorbase.org/popbio/map/asolr/solr/vb_popbio/smplGeoclust?q=*&fq=geo_coords:[44.731125592643274,-18.9404296875%20TO%2055.26659815231191,22.873535156249996]&stats.facet=geohash_3&facet.pivot=geohash_3,species_category&json.wrf=jQuery110206188232152791343_1464644641028&callback=?&_=1464644641034
```

May be you should try to contact them ?

Answer (score 4):

In general, yes, in theory, yes, in practice, yes with a bit of work. There's no general general solution because you can't know how the data is coming from the server. The solution involves looking at the underlying Javascript and seeing what it does. Chances are it will be an AJAX call to a server that returns a geoJSON data set, but it could literally be anything. If AJAX and geoJSON mean nothing to you then I doubt you'll be able to write something to do it for any given site.

That said, the site you reference has a big fat "Downloads" button which is clearly the recommended way to get the data you want rather than trying to reverse engineer their web map system. Use that.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman! Although I should say that the fat "Downloads" button does not refer to the georeferenced data!